# Spring StateMachine restart seems to cache last execution

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-statemachine

I have configured a Spring State Machine with the following states and transitions:

IDLE (initial) -> STARTED -> PRE_SNAPSHOT (pre-snapshot action)-> SNAPSHOT (snapshot action)-> IDLE

Here is my configuration:

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class StateMachineConfiguration extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    public static final String IDLE = "IDLE";
    public static final String STARTED = "STARTED";
    public static final String PRE_SNAPSHOT = "PRE_SNAPSHOT";
    public static final String SNAPSHOT = "SNAPSHOT";
    public static final String START_EVENT = "START_EVENT";

    @Autowired
    private PreSnapshotActionMock preSnapshotActionMock;

    @Autowired
    private SnapshotActionMock snapshotActionMock;

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration().autoStartup(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<String, String> stateConfigurer) throws Exception {
        stateConfigurer
                .withStates()
                .initial(IDLE)
                .state(STARTED)
                .stateDo(PRE_SNAPSHOT, preSnapshotActionMock)
                .stateDo(SNAPSHOT, snapshotActionMock)
                .end(IDLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitionConfigurer) throws Exception {
        transitionConfigurer
                .withExternal().source(IDLE).target(STARTED).event(START_EVENT)
                .and()
                .withExternal().source(STARTED).target(PRE_SNAPSHOT)
                .and()
                .withExternal().source(PRE_SNAPSHOT).target(SNAPSHOT)
                .and()
                .withExternal().source(SNAPSHOT).target(IDLE);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachine<String, String> testStateMachine(@Autowired StateMachineFactory<String, String> smFactory) throws Exception {
        return smFactory.getStateMachine();
    }
}
```

In my case I want to mock a long execution of the actions, but in separate test cases for each. For this I am using Mockito's `AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay()`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(StateMachineConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class StateMachineTest {

    @MockBean
    private PreSnapshotActionMock preSnapshotActionMock;

    @MockBean
    private SnapshotActionMock snapshotActionMock;

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<String, String> testStateMachine;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        Answer preSnapshotAnswer = AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(10, invocation -> {
            System.out.println("default pre-snapshot action short execution");
            return null;
        });
        doAnswer(preSnapshotAnswer).when(preSnapshotActionMock).execute(any());

        Answer snapshotAnswer = AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(10, invocation -> {
            System.out.println("default snapshot action short execution");
            return null;
        });
        doAnswer(snapshotAnswer).when(snapshotActionMock).execute(any());

        testStateMachine.start();
    }

    @After
    public void reset() throws InterruptedException {
        testStateMachine.stop();
        testStateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().withRegion().resetStateMachine(
                new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(IDLE, null, null, null));
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }

    @Test
    //here I mock long execution for pre-snapshot action only
    public void test1() {

        Answer answerWithDelay = AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(10, invocation -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                System.out.println("pre-snapshot action from test1 #" + i);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            }
            return null;
        });
        doAnswer(answerWithDelay).when(preSnapshotActionMock).execute(any());

        StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String> stateChangeListenerSpy = Mockito.spy(StateMachineListenerAdapter.class);
        testStateMachine.addStateListener(stateChangeListenerSpy);

        Assertions.assertThat(testStateMachine.sendEvent(START_EVENT)).isTrue();

        Mockito.verify(stateChangeListenerSpy, Mockito.timeout(10_000).times(2)).stateEntered(any());
        Mockito.verify(stateChangeListenerSpy, Mockito.timeout(10_000).times(2)).stateExited(any());

        testStateMachine.removeStateListener(stateChangeListenerSpy);
    }

    @Test
    //here I mock long execution for snapshot action only
    public void test2() {

        Answer answerWithDelay = AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(10, invocation -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10) {
                System.out.println("snapshot action from test2 #" + i);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            }
            return null;
        });
        doAnswer(answerWithDelay).when(snapshotActionMock).execute(any());

        StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String> stateChangeListenerSpy = Mockito.spy(StateMachineListenerAdapter.class);
        testStateMachine.addStateListener(stateChangeListenerSpy);

        System.out.println("Sending start event now");
        Assertions.assertThat(testStateMachine.sendEvent(START_EVENT)).isTrue();

        Mockito.verify(stateChangeListenerSpy, Mockito.timeout(10000).times(3)).stateEntered(any());
        Mockito.verify(stateChangeListenerSpy, Mockito.timeout(10000).times(3)).stateExited(any());

        testStateMachine.removeStateListener(stateChangeListenerSpy);
    }
}
```

First test case passes, because state machine is performing long execution of pre-snapshot action, which is expected. Second test, though, is failing, because **again pre-snapshot action seems to be executing slowly.** What is more interesting is if I change the sleep time in test1 from 10_000 to just 100, here is the log from both tests:

test1:

```
pre-snapshot action from test1 #0
pre-snapshot action from test1 #1
pre-snapshot action from test1 #2
pre-snapshot action from test1 #3
```

test2:

```
Sending start event now
pre-snapshot action from test1 #4
pre-snapshot action from test1 #5
pre-snapshot action from test1 #6
pre-snapshot action from test1 #7
pre-snapshot action from test1 #8
pre-snapshot action from test1 #9
snapshot action from test2 #0
```

It seems that even though I have configured a default behaviour of the actions in the @Before method, in test2 it is not executed at all and instead **pre-snapshot action is continuing its work from where it stopped in test1**, only after then state machine is transiting to SNAPSHOT state.

If I configure exactly the same state machine and test cases as unit tests, here is the log from test2:

```
Sending start event now
default pre-snapshot action short execution
snapshot action from test2 #0
pre-snapshot action from test1 #4
pre-snapshot action from test1 #5
pre-snapshot action from test1 #6
```

which shows the opposite (and expected in my opinion) behaviour: first the default pre-snapshot action is executed.

Do you think this might be a bug in the State Machine or am I missing something here? I agree this can be some recovery mechanism, but if so it is not very compatible with mocking. Initially, I thought the reason might be in Mockito's AnswersWithDelay, but since I tested it with other objects it doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: You don't happen to have this code or relevant parts I could checkout and run myself? Also I'm not sure what happens when you define IDLE as initial and terminal state as that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for response, Janne. I have managed to workaround this in our project's situation. My goal was to be able to stop the current state's action in case I want to revert to some previous state. I have achieved this by calling sate.exit() and handled "InterruptedException" in the action itself. Is this the common way?